# Правильно ли согласовано?

Tags: согласование

"Поначалу он просто пожалел их, несчастных, искалеченных человеческих существ..." Что-то меня терзают смутные сомнения - правильно тут согласование употреблено или нет. Пожалел существ или существа?
Заранее спасибо за подсказку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно. Существительное "существо" одушевленное. Пожалел (кого?) существ (родительный падеж множественного числа)